# Modern SharePoint CAML query with multiple criteria

Tags: sharepoint, caml

I am new to CAML. CAML seems like a great way to filter lists, but I am struggling to write nested and/or statements.

I am trying to start out small and write one CAML query with only two conditions so I can get the hang of it. Below is my failed attempt.

```
<View>
<Query>
<Where>
    <and>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name='PracticeArea_x0028_s_x0029_' />
            <Value Type='Text'>Lean</Value>
        </Contains>
        <NotInclude>
            <FieldRef Name='PracticeArea_x0028_s_x0029_' />
            <Value Type='Text'>,</Value>
        </NotInclude>
    </and>
</Where>
</Query>
</View>
```

Any help, support, and/or insight this community can provide is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

NotInclude used for Lookup field that allows multiple values, so won't work if you filter against a text field.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/notincludes-element-query

You could filter by Contains first and then filter by Linq or similar approach.

```
 SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("TestFilter");
                    SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();                        
                    spQuery.Query = @"<Where>                                          
                                            <Contains>
                                            <FieldRef Name='PracticeArea' />
                                            <Value Type='Text'>Lean</Value>
                                            </Contains>                                                                                         
                                       </Where>";
                    var items = list.GetItems(spQuery);
                    var filterItems=items.Cast<SPListItem>().Where(item => string.Format("{0}",item["PracticeArea"]).IndexOf(',') <0);
                    Console.WriteLine(filterItems.Count());
```